# Does Combat Opening use an immediate action?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, optimization

Combat Opening is a feat from Martial Power which says:

> When you **can** make a melee basic attack against a target because of Combat Challenge, you can instead choose to let an ally make a melee basic attack against that target as a free action.

Does this cost an Immediate Action for me, or not? I **can** make a melee basic attack if the trigger is fulfilled several times in a round, if I spend the action, but I only have one Immediate Action.
So the real question is: when **can** I make a melee basic attack, if the trigger is activated, or when I actually spend the action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What kind of action does this cost?

This uses an immediate action. When it says:

> you can instead choose to let an ally make a melee basic attack against that target **as a free action.**

The free action is what your ally uses to perform the attack, not what you use to enact this effect. Enacting it still takes an immediate action.

### This is just convention

All powers or effects which grant free actions to allies are worded this way. D&D 4e's authors *love* following convention in the core rulebooks, and this is just another instance of the same convention being used. A browse of the Shaman or Warlord power lists will turn up several occurrences of this same convention.

Consider, for instance, the Warlord's *Hammer and Anvil* power, an encounter power, which says:

> One ally adjacent to the target makes a **melee basic attack against it as a free action.**

Or the Shaman's *Ancient Warlord's Inspiration*, a daily power, which says:

> If an ally starts his or her turn adjacent to the spirit or in its space, as an immediate
>   reaction you can **allow that ally to make a basic attack as a free action.**

These powers still take a standard action to use. There'd be absolutely no point to saying *you* use a free action to grant the attack, since you're already granting it as one of the side-effects of your standard action-costing power.

## When can you use this?

> So the real question is: when can I make a melee basic attack, if the trigger is activated, or when I actually spend the action?

You can use this when you can spend the action.

The trigger is:

> When you can make a melee basic attack against a target because of Combat Challenge

You can only make a melee basic attack because of Combat Challenge if you *actually use* Combat Challenge (which takes an immediate interrupt) to grant you a melee basic attack. Then, instead of performing that melee basic attack, you let someone else do it instead.

This effect just modifies Combat Challenge. It doesn't grant your allies free attacks constantly.

Comment: The "instead" could apply to you spending and Immediate.

Comment: @Andras It doesn't. I've edited to address that interpretation more thoroughly.

Comment: It might help to frame combat challenge into a proper power card. What's happening here is that the *effect* line of the Combat Challenge power card (if one existed) is being replaced by "allow an ally to make an MBA". Acuatlly it *is* a power card see: http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=power&id=7419

Comment: As a note- the reason why it's important to say that they can make an attack "as a free action" is because characters have a one free action attack per turn limit.  So if a leader allowed an ally to make a free action attack, and then somehow Combat Challenge was invoked, they can't also make a free action attack from your Combat Opening/Combat Challenge combination.